# Convert application/octet-stream to image/jpeg/png in flutter?

Tags: ios, firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-storage

I was trying to upload image to Firebase Store using [Imagepicker](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker) library,

But in console it's showing the format as application/octet-stream because of that the image is not visible. Is there any possible way to convert that format to image  in dart itself while uploading.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Either pass a file extension to the file name when you upload

```
FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child(path)
        .child('image.jpg');
```

or pass metadata

```
FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child(path)
        .child('image');
imageStore.putFile(file, StorageMetadata(contentType: 'image/jpeg'));
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#add_file_metadata

> ### Add File Metadata
>
> When uploading a file, you can also specify metadata
>   for that file. This metadata contains typical file metadata properties
>   such as name, size, and contentType (commonly referred to as MIME
>   type). Cloud Storage automatically infers the content type from the
>   file extension where the file is stored on disk, but if you specify a
>   contentType in the metadata it will override the auto-detected type.
>   If no contentType metadata is specified and the file doesn't have a
>   file extension, Cloud Storage defaults to the type
>   application/octet-stream. More information on file metadata can be
>   found in the Use File Metadata section.