# Firebase storage file type is 'octet-stream' instead of 'png/jpg'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage, file-type

I'm trying to upload images to the firebase storage. When I upload them to the storage, I see them with a type: `application/octet-stream` instead of `image/jpeg` or `image/png`.

This is the code I use:

```
<input
  type="file"
  id="img"
  name="filename"
  accept="image/*"
  onChange={(e) => {
    handleChange(e);
  }}
/>

const handleChange = async (e) => {
  const imgRef = await firebase.storage().ref('images/' + image.name);
  await imgRef.put(img);
 };
```

The file gets uploaded to the storage, but with the wrong file type. The documentation of firebase storage tells us that when you upload a file without a file extension it automatically gets the application/octet-stream type. `If no contentType metadata is specified and the file doesn't have a file extension, Cloud Storage defaults to the type application/octet-stream.` This is really strange because they are uploaded to the firebase storage with the right file extension.

[image]

Comment: You need to pass a name with an extension or pass `contentType` via metadata. See this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54303172/2144912

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this solution will apply to your case:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54303172

You need to either specify the file extension using `.child()` or add content type metadata to your upload file.

Answer (score 1):

Can add meta data like that:

```
storageRef.put(file, {
    contentType: 'image/png',
})
```